# Laravel 9 on Apache - tailwind.config.js does not work?

Tags: php, laravel, git, tailwind-css

Project on Apache, pushed to prod via `git clone` and every change `git pull origin master`.

I've got issue, because I've configured file `tailwind.config.js` with some images which I store in `.\public\img` directory inside the project:

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: [
        './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
        './storage/framework/views/*.php',
        './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
        './app/Http/Livewire/**/*Table.php',
        './resources/vendor/livewire-powergrid/resources/views/**/*.php',
        './resources/vendor/livewire-powergrid/src/Themes/Tailwind.php',
    ],

    theme: {
        extend: {
            fontFamily: {
                sans: ['Nunito', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
            },
            backgroundImage: {
                'waves': "url('/public/img/wave.svg')",
                'top-waves': "url('/public/img/top-wave.svg')",
            }
        },
    },

    plugins: [
        require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
    ],
};
```

I mean after deployment, the `backgroundImage` are not visible... Not throwing any errors.
I've run `npm run build` for production, but it loads them to:

```
> build
> vite build

vite v4.0.4 building for production...
✓ 146 modules transformed.
public/build/manifest.json               0.36 kB
public/build/assets/wave-4d586f34.svg    1.95 kB
public/build/assets/app-96952338.css    43.40 kB │ gzip:  7.62 kB
public/build/assets/app-b4751d01.js    201.58 kB │ gzip: 65.51 kB
```

No error inside dev tools...

Image is loaded inside component like:

`<div class="bg-waves">Blablabla</div>` and it seems to be not readable.

I've edited also `livewire.php` config, because I've got issue to use `LivewirePowergrid` library.

Anyone has similar problem?

Comment: Are you using Laravel Mix, or Vite, or something else?

Comment: I'm using Laravel Vite.